# mongoDB sharded cluster and chunks

Tags: mongodb

I'm quite newbie on mongoDB and I'm wondering if it is normal if I don't have any chunk on a mongodb sharded cluster ?

Let me illustrate. I've got three shards :

```
mongos> use config
mongos> db.getSiblingDB("config").shards.find()
{ "_id" : "shard1", ... }
{ "_id" : "shard2", ... }
{ "_id" : "shard3", ... }
mongos>
```

I've got some databases, and especially one on shard1:

```
mongos> db.getSiblingDB("config").databases.find()
{ "_id" : "udev_prod", "partitioned" : false, "primary" : "shard1" }
```

But no chunks at all... :

```
mongos> db.getSiblingDB("config").chunks.find()
mongos>
```

on top of that, if I connect to the udev_prod database and try to get the sharded distribution of any collection, mongoDB tells me it's not sharded...

```
mongos> db.User.getShardDistribution()
Collection udev_prod.User is not sharded.
```

I think that I'm missing something here, or it is not working well.. could someone tell me if that situation is "normal" ?

Thanks a lot

Best Regards

Julien

Comment: I think sharding is not enabled for the database (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.enableSharding/#sh.enableSharding) and you need to define a shard key on the collection (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.shardCollection/#sh.shardCollection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the key piece from your find on databases:

```
"partitioned" : false
```

That means that the database does not have sharding enabled.  You need to [enable sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.enableSharding/#sh.enableSharding) for the database first, and then [shard a collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.shardCollection/#sh.shardCollection) (and [pick a shard key](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/)) before any chunks are created.  Otherwise the database just lives on one shard - it's still usable, just not sharded.

There is a full tutorial available for setting up a sharded cluster with sharded collections, [this is the section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#enable-sharding-for-a-database) you want to start with.